# How to create a executable jar file without any GUI component?

Tags: java, jar, io, ide, executable-jar

I have just created a program that uses file I/O and ***for interactive input and output it uses terminal window of IDE.*** I want to create a executable jar file of this program. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

I am using BlueJ as IDE.
The program have `**no GUI component**`

I have created a jar using BlueJ but it does not works.. When I double click on jar nothing happens...

Comment: As a side note to the answers, if you're using Ubuntu, or another Linux distro, you will need to mark the jar as executable otherwise it's handled as an archive.

Comment: I am using Windows 7..

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an `Main-Class` entry in your Manifest. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for details.

Given yours example

```
public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String agrs[]) {
                System.out.println("magic");
                 MainClass.interning_behaviour("12");
        }

        public static void interning_behaviour(String string_input)     {
                String string="12";
                String string_5;
                string_5=string_input.substring(0);
                System.out.println(string==string_5);
        }
}
```

1) You have to compile it: `javac MainClass.java`

2) You have to jar it `jar cfe MainClass.jar MainClass MainClass.class`

3) Now you can run it `java -jar MainClass.jar`

Comment: I can create a **executable** jar file with GUI... But if the jar have no GUI then what to do??

Comment: You have to have `public static void main(String[] args)` which will be executed, when the jar is run.

Comment: No such thing happens... Again my program do not have any GUI and it used IDE for interactive input and output.

Comment: For example,

`public class main
{
    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        System.out.println("magic");
        main.interning_behaviour("12");
    }
    
    public static void interning_behaviour(String string_input)
    {
        String string="12";
        String string_5;
        string_5=string_input.substring(0);
        System.out.println(string==string_5);
    }
}`

Comment: I have already created a jar file using BlueJ... But it is not working. I dont know where to type `jar cfe MainClass.jar MainClass MainClass.class` and frm where to run.. I am just a Beginner.

Answer (score 0):

basically you should type:
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

You can find usage details at link below:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the IDE you're using.
In eclipse for example you can do this by right-clicking the package in package explorer window and navigating `Export ->Java -> JAR file`.

Comment: Where is package explorer window ??

Comment: I can create a executable jar file with GUI... But if the jar have no GUI then what to do??

Comment: The windows is *by default) on the right side of eclipse window.

Comment: Sorry! I use NetBean and BlueJ... Well the problem is to create a executable jar that actually works...

Answer (score 0):

Export as a runnable jar if you're in eclipse

Comment: Right click on project, export, java, runnable jar file, select main class, finish

Comment: Well then this won't help you!